# Nominal or ordinal variable?

Tags: spss, ordinal-data, categorical-data

[image: Variable with four categories]

Is this variable nominal or ordinal?

Comment: Looks ordinal to me, but why are you unsure?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is of very poor quality and does not aim at understanding the concepts of ordinal and nominal variables.

Comment: I expect someone is just trying to get people to do their homework; I'd have closed as self study myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks ordinal to my eyes as the answer can be 0,1,2,3 and this is linked with ordered values of d